# Read numbers in a string with any number of digits in python

Tags: python

I am having trouble in parsing my string. Here are my codes:

```
name='report 11 hits'
print(name[7:9])
print(name[11:])
```

output:

```
11
hits
```

But, if I need to type the string as

```
name='report 112 hits'
print(name[7:9])
print(name[10:])
```

output:

```
11
 hits
```

That means, whenever I am typing a number more than three digits, the program is not reading it well. I was wondering if someone could write me how to modify my code in such a way that no matter what digit I write, the program will read it correctly. Thanks.

Comment: That heavily depends on the string to be parsed. Is it always `name` guaranteed that `name` will have that format? `report <number> hits`?

Comment: Yes, the name has to be REPORT n HITS or REPORT n BATTING or REPORT n SLUGGING format.

Comment: Then I vote for `split` :) Better to use regex when they're really needed :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `split()` and then print the second element of the generated list:

```
name='report 112 hits'
namelist = name.split()
print(namelist[0])
# report
print(namelist[1])
# 112
print(namelist[2])
# hits
```

Comment: Inefficient split, if there will be more columns. Check [mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22468281/1903116)

Comment: @thefourtheye Check comments, the string won't have more than 3 columns. I don't think it will make a big different to limit the number of splits

Answer (score 1):

```
name='report 112 hits'
import re
print re.search(r'\d+', name).group()
# 112
```

But if you know for sure that the number will be the second element in the string, separated by a space, then you can do

```
print name.split(None, 2)[1]
# 112
```

This split will be efficient as we limit the maximum splitting by 2.

Comment: Think of all the nanoseconds!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there will always be spaces:

```
_, count, hits = name.split(" ")
print(count)
print(hits)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are guaranteed that the string is always 'report ### hits' where ### is some number of digits, you could do:

```
name = 'report 11155342 hits'
print name.split()[1]
print name.split()[2]
```

Comment: Is this splitting multiple times, or will it be optimized to perform only one split?

Comment: Inefficient split, if there will be more columns. Check [mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22468281/1903116)

Comment: Yes, I suppose it will take twice as long as optimal, performing a split of roughly 20 characters is not very intensive though...

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

name='report 11155342 hits'

print(re.findall(r'\d+', name)[0])
```

prints:

```
11155342
```